# MySQL integration with MS Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I shall need to integrate MySQL 5.7 with MS Access (2007 and above) in two ways, so I send data from MySQL to MS Access and accept data from MS Access. This is a recurring task, so I shall need to set an automated routine to do so. Any ready to use tools or procedures?

Comment: Can set links to MySQL tables. Build forms to enter data. Write code for special requirements. When you have specific issue post question.

Comment: This is the specific issue, I know how to integrate MySQL with MS Access, the reason of this question is how to set it up so it runs daily? What you suggest is to use MS Access as a front and MySQL as backend. Our use case is different, there are two independent system, we need to integrate them.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Answers would be primarily opinion-based. Stackoverflow is intended for more focused questions on specific programming issues - someone has actual code needing refinement. I have used a VBScript to call a procedure within Access VBA. I run the script by schedule set in Windows Task Manager. I am sure there are many options - do you know PowerShell?

Comment: I understand that the answers could be multiple. I did some research but could not find a simple way to automate the task. Writing some code would be the last option. Someone has to maintain it so I am with ready to use solution.

Comment: If you're looking for ready-to-use solutions, and don't wish to write any code, Stack Overflow is totally the wrong place for you (it's a site for professional and enthusiast programmers, and programmers tend to write code). However, you're in luck with Gustav's solution, because linking external tables is one of the things built into Access itself.

Comment: All the applications are written by the programmers and I just wanted to find a result of work of other programmers without inventing a wheel. Gustav's answer is not what I want as we don't want to link the tables, these systems are separate. The answer I am looking for is if MySQL provides an ETL solution which I can schedule.

Comment: Well, Access provides lots of import/export tools, such as `DoCmd.TransferDatabase`, but that's code.

Comment: Search gave me some open source ETL tools, so I shall explorer  in this direction.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [ODBC driver for MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/) and link the tables you wish to "integrate".